# CSS Declaration in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: css

This is my 1st post here so bare with me ... I am very new :)

I have got SP Designer 2010 up and running, I am starting to reference CSS files saved in the 'Style Library'. Everything is working well, but I get Designer showing an error for tag ...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Style%20Library/_emedia/css/emedia-reset.css">
```

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I see is a / to self close the tag. Other than that it should be fine.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Style%20Library/_emedia/css/emedia-reset.css" />
```

Comment: Although not very applicable for SharePoint because of doctype it is interesting to know that [link element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element) is actually a void element (empty content model), so that will be interesting for SharePoint 2016 =)